# View.OnKeyListener for soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the View.OnKeyListener for EditText to do something when some special keys are pressed/touched. Here is a shorthened version of the code:

```
public class MyKeyListener implements View.OnKeyListener{
    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                // do some processing
                return true;
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0) {
                // do another processing
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the OnKeyListener, according to the documentation, is only guaranteed to be called when hard keyboards are used. And, indeed, I tested it on some phones where it doesn't work for soft keyboards. So I was wondering if there is something similar to this listener that would work for soft keyboards.

Comment: The correct listener to use for soft keyboards is OnKeyboardActionListener 
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not guaranteed, you can't.

You can use a `TextWatcher` and attach that to any and all EditTexts.

Or, you create your own `KeyboardView` and force the user to use that one, then you can attach the expected listeners to it. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html?hl=ja#IMEUI

Comment: The problem with TextWatcher is that I cannot detect backspaces with it.

Comment: backspace as in like delete? technically, you can, compare curr and prev string length. anyways, using textwatcher will be tricky business, some special cases you will need to set for, using both textwatcher and your onKeyListener.