# Numbers key soft keyboard responded to the onKeyListener

Tags: android, onkeylistener

I have an Edittext with OnKeyListener. The problem is that the numbers keys in the soft keyboard (0-9) responded to the onKeyListener. In the documentation of View.OnKeyListener in developers.android.com says:

"Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before the key event is given to the view. This is only useful for hardware keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener."

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282214/onkeylistener-not-working-on-virtual-keyboard

Comment: Sorry...I mean this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957122/view-onkeylistener-for-soft-keyboard